# Unable to run Rest API Command

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processdefinitions/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/layout?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

In the above command I use the full URL of workItemTypes(witRefName) but still not getting any output. I have tried using the work item names like Epic and that does not work either. Does anyone know what goes in there or what I am missing? The command I user before this is

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processdefinitions/{processId}/workitemtypes?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this API (get all work item types) :

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processdefinitions/{processId}/workitemtypes?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

Output :

```
"id": "Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug",
"name": "Bug",
"description": "Describes a divergence between required and actual behavior, and tracks the work done to correct the defect and verify the correction.",
"url": "https://dev.azure.com/domain/_apis/work/processDefinitions/processId/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug",
"inherits": null,
"class": "system",
"color": "CC293D",
"icon": "icon_insect",
"isDisabled": false
```

The `witRefName` keyword is the `id` from the last response, `Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug`

And here's the new url to get layout :

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug/layout?api-version=7.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did figure out that the layout Restapi command is different from what is the documents as you mentioned in your Answer. The layout command for customized fields return null data? Do you know how I can achieve that?